# Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?

Tags: java, weka

I am using Weka

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
.
.
DataSource source;
source = new DataSource("somecsvfile.csv");
```

I get following printed on console in red color in eclipse:

```
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. weka.jar has a [DatabaseUtils.props](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props) file in it. This file has following line in subversion therefore weka tries to load that drivers.

```
jdbcDriver=RmiJdbc.RJDriver,jdbc.idbDriver,org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver,com.mckoi.JDBCDriver,org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

Open jar file with a zip utility and look for weka\experiment\DatabaseUtils.props file.

Comment: yes, I found that line. I'm not using any database and loading data using CSV files only. Can I safely ignore this error?

Comment: yes, you can ignore it safely. Comment out that line if you want

Comment: @Atilla Ozgur thanks today your answer help me to solve my problem thanks again dude.... +1