# WEKA JDBC complaining when trying to read CSV File

Tags: java, weka

I am having a hard time finding a good tutorial for WEKA using its k-Means methods. Here is the code:

```
    System.out.println("loading training data");
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    // Read all the instances in the file (ARFF, CSV, XRFF, ...)
    Instances instances = null;
    try {
        DataSource source = new DataSource(path+"/data/train/class1_1.csv");
        instances = source.getDataSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return;
    }
    System.out.println("training data loaded");

    // Make the last attribute be the class
    instances.setClassIndex(instances.numAttributes() - 1);

    // Print header and instances.
    System.out.println("\ndataset:\n");
    System.out.println(instances);
```

I am getting the error:

```
loading training data
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add JDBC driver: RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add JDBC driver: jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add JDBC driver: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add JDBC driver: com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add JDBC driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:179)
    at java.io.StreamTokenizer.read(StreamTokenizer.java:500)
    at java.io.StreamTokenizer.nextToken(StreamTokenizer.java:544)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.getFirstToken(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getDataSet(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.getDataSet(Unknown Source)
    at hmm.HMM.run(HMM.java:49)
    at hmm.HMM.main(HMM.java:19)
training data loadedException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hmm.HMM.run(HMM.java:58)
    at hmm.HMM.main(HMM.java:19)
```

Here is a photo of the csv file:
[image]

I am not even trying to connect to a database, I am trying to read a csv file I have. Anyone know how to load multiple csv files with weka?

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to read a valid csv file?

Comment: BTW: the code you pasted and the exception you pasted are from different sources. In your code most probably there is no `return` in the exception handling block. Also this has nothing to do to JDBC, those are just diagnostic messages.

Comment: @GáborBakos Indeed I am sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that JDBC warning messages are nothing to worry about, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343145/trying-to-add-database-driver-jdbc-rmijdbc-rjdriver-error-not-in-classpath/15350557#15350557).

Following code read csv files and output its contents to console, see in [github](https://github.com/ati-ozgur/WekaExamples).

```
package wekaExamples.loadDatasetExamples;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.*;

import java.io.*;


/**
 * Created by atilla.ozgur on 17.12.2014.
 */
public class LoadCsvExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("loading training data");

        Instances instances = null;
        try {
            String fileName = "./data/deneme1.csv";

            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
            loader.setSource(new File(fileName));
            instances = loader.getDataSet();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return;
        }
        System.out.println("training data loaded");

        // Make the last attribute be the class
        instances.setClassIndex(instances.numAttributes() - 1);

        // Print header and instances.
        System.out.println("\ndataset:\n");
        System.out.println(instances);
    }

}
```

Output is as following:

```
loading training data
training data loaded

dataset:

@relation deneme1

@attribute x numeric
@attribute y numeric

@data
1,2
2,3
1,4
```

Comment: Booyaa and your example works perfect, I've been all over WEKA's website but nothing worked!

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [ConverterUtils.DataSource](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/ConverterUtils.DataSource.html#ConverterUtils.DataSource%28java.lang.String%29) docs:

```
Tries to load the data from the file. Can be either a regular file or a web location (http://, https://, ftp:// or file://).
```

So I believe you're missing the `file://` in path.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: weka.core.converters.CSVLoader cannot be cast to weka.core.converters.URLSourcedLoader
 at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.reset(Unknown Source)
 at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at hmm.HMM.run(HMM.java:38)
 at hmm.HMM.main(HMM.java:19)