# Converting CSV to ARFF

Tags: java, csv, jdbc, weka

My code is:

```
package csvtoarff;

import java.io.File;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;

public class CsvToArff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String f1 = "C://Users//user//Desktop//testfold//test.csv";
            String f2 = "C://Users//user//Desktop//testfold//output.arff";

            // load the CSV file (input file)
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
            loader.setSource(new File(f1));
            String [] options = new String[1];
            options[0]="-H";
            loader.setOptions(options);

            Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
            System.out.println(data);

            // save as an  ARFF (output file)
            ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
            saver.setInstances(data);
            saver.setFile(new File(f2));
            saver.setDestination(new File(f2));
            saver.writeBatch();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Error is:

> ---Registering Weka Editors--- Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?

[This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15350557/983430) doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343145/trying-to-add-database-driver-jdbc-rmijdbc-rjdriver-error-not-in-classpath/15350557#15350557

Comment: the link provided above doesnot give me solution.please, anyone knows it give me solution or at least hint to overcome it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add the InstantDB-driver to your classpath as it is mentioned in the  error-message?

Comment: but i am not using any database. just trying to load the .csv file and output will be .arff file. that's it...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found answer.

Actually need not to worry about that error of database.just leave it as it is.
and just mark comment to the line:
" saver.setDestination(new File(f2));" because i am using newer version of weka and it does not need that line.

Comment: yeah, I was about to write:  I for one can run your code with weka 3.6 as it is, with different input files of course. - You could add 1 line of code in th Exception handler: `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: yes,You are right. I found solution by printing stack trace. Thanks.