# Cannot start Weka - getting error

Tags: java, weka

I have successfully installed Weka and need it to connect to our MS SQL Server. But when I start Weka I get the below error:

```
# java -Xmx1000M -jar weka.jar
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
```

Where I can get a the .jar or lib files where I have only the below listed .jar files:

```
# find . -name "*.jar"
./weka.jar
./weka-src.jar
./remoteExperimentServer.jar
[weka-3-6-12]#
```

What else I need to install to run Weka successfully.

As per the comment below this is the content of my "weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props" file:

```
# grep -i idbDriver weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props

#jdbcDriver=RmiJdbc.RJDriver,jdbc.idbDriver
#jdbcDriver=jdbc.idbDriver
#jdbcDriver=RmiJdbc.RJDriver,jdbc.idbDriver,org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver,com.mckoi.JDBCDriver,org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

Since every line starts with '#' that has jdbc.idbDriver I believe that these lines are comment. Am I correct in my understanding - also I believe that this warning / error which can be ignored.

But please let me know what changes I need to make to connect Weka to MS SQL Databases?

Comment: Did you see this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343145/trying-to-add-database-driver-jdbc-rmijdbc-rjdriver-error-not-in-classpath

Comment: @SemihEker Thanks I have updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable connectivity to MSSQL via weka, do this:
(do [this](https://andersspur.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/connect-weka-to-sql-server-2012-and-14/) if you are on windows)

1. create a start script
2. create a DatabaseUtils.props file

Here is my startscript. Note how the $CP variable is set. This contains the full path to the jtds.jar file which contains the jdbc driver for MSSQL.

```
#!/bin/bash
WEKA_HOME=/opt/smallapps/weka-stable/weka
export WEKA_JAR=$WEKA_HOME/weka.jar
export PATH=$WEKA_HOME:$PATH
CP="/usr/share/java/:/opt/dbvis9/jdbc/jtds/jtds.jar:/opt/database/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc.jar:$WEKA_JAR"
echo "used CLASSPATH: $CP"
DIR=/opt/smallapps/weka-stable/data/
echo "changing to '$DIR'"
cd "$DIR"
export WEKA_HOME=$DIR
# start Weka's small GUIChooser window
java -cp $CP -Xmx500m weka.gui.GUIChooser &
```

This is the beginning  my DatabaseUtils.props file, comments removed, stored at its default location. 
My full path: `/opt/smallapps/weka/wekafiles/DatabaseUtils-mssql.props`,
linked to `/opt/smallapps/weka/wekafiles/DatabaseUtils.props`

```
jdbcDriver=org.sqlite.JDBC,net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

jdbcURL=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbhost.mycompany.com:1433;DatabaseName=master

varchar=0
float=2
numeric=2
tinyint=3
int=5
bigint=6
nvarchar=9
nchar=9
char=9
decimal=2
bit=1
smallint=5
date=8
```

Here I have addded a screenshot with the buttons to click.

Note that there are no "Connection successful" messages. There will appear only yellow-triangle messages in the console window. (Red X - Icons if connection unsuccessful)

[image]

Connection URLs documentation by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am sorry - but right now I am facing issues like I cannot edit or enter any chars in weka input text boxes - I have stated weka thru a Windows X Server tool - Xming - weka is installed in Linux box - the app comes up fine but I am not able to enter user / passwd for DB connections - also it states - exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xx:1433

Comment: OK I changed my weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props to have jdbcDriver=com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver and I restarted the tool I get the below error : Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?

Comment: I don't know how to connect with the MSSQL driver. Specificallly, I don't know in which jar file it is in. Find it, and then replace the full path to jtds.jar with your path to your jar. Instead of using my shell script, you can start weka with `java -cp <yourMSSQLserverJDBC.jar> weka.jar`

Comment: Thanks I am now getting the below error: [weka-3-6-12]# java -Xmx1000M -jar weka.jar -cp sqljdbc41.jar
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
java.lang.NullPointerException
        weka.gui.GUIChooser.showExplorer(GUIChooser.java:1247)
        weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:1528)

        at weka.gui.GUIChooser.showExplorer(GUIChooser.java:1247)
        at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:1528)

I have downloaded sqljdbc41.jar from MS website

Comment: add the *full path* to sqljdbc41.jar  to the -cp argument

Comment: OK got it working .. no errors reported - but I am not able to edit any input text boxes of weka explorer .. like I want to enter the connect string to my MS SQL Server - when I click on the user input box its just does not echoes what I am typing from keyboard

Comment: Cannot say. Did you send Weka in the background with  `&`, and it is now hanging as a stopped job? Alternatively, might be remote-desktop problem. Sorry, you are on your own then.

Comment: Thanks for all the details - it really helped me and also I switched to MobaXterm http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net - it resolved all my X Client windows issues. Thanks a lot & tons

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps below. It works for me too but for MySQL. It may be similar within MSSQL. I tried to edit for MSSQL.

1- Download the required Connector from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

2- According to your Java version "mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar, mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre11.jar, mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre15.jar" (These are "sqljdbc_9_2 \ enu" folder they are included) copy the files to the "Weka" folder. You can copy all of them.

3- Then you must enter CLASSPATH value in "Environment Variables" in capital letters. If you are using Windows 7 you will see CLASSPATH already. However, if you are using Windows 10, you may need to add manually. It was like this on my computer:
[image: Classpath on Windows 7]

4- Copy the DatabaseUtils.probs file to the Weka folder. This file allows you to match the data types in the database with Weka's own data types. If some data types do not match, you must set them in this file.

5- Then you have to open Weka from the start menu. It doesn't work when you turn it on from the console. You don't need a console anyway. You can set the amount of RAM memory in "RunWeka.ini" in the Weka folder.

6- Click Open DB. Enter information on the screen as follows. Remember, if the password is incorrect, JDBC driver error may still occur.
[image: DB Setting]
[image: Connection]